# OData V4.0: Auto-assign primary key when creating an entity

Tags: odata, odata-v4

I'm working with an OData V4.0 API and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to properly create an entity. I'm using this [OData V4.0 reference service](http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/).

My "naive" assumption (based on how most databases work), is that when POSTing an entity to a collection, I would omit the primary key and let the service generate it and return it to me in the response.

In other words, when I'm making the following request:

```
POST http://services.odata.org/Experimental/OData/(S(<SessionID>))/OData.svc/Products
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "@odata.type": "ODataDemo.Product",
  "Name": "Widget",
  "Description": "A simple widget",
  "ReleaseDate": "1991-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "DiscontinuedDate": null,
  "Rating": 4,
  "Price": 2.5
}
```

I'm expecting an answer with status code `201 Created` and a `Location` header like `http://services.odata.org/Experimental/OData/(S(<SessionID>))/OData.svc/Products(11)`.

Instead, I receive the following error:

```
The serialized resource has a null value in key member 'ID'. 
Null values are not supported in key members.
```

So I figured, perhaps I can just set this to an arbitrary value, and the service will simply ignore it and issue its own ID. So I try the following request:

```
POST http://services.odata.org/Experimental/OData/(S(<SessionID>))/OData.svc/Products
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "@odata.type": "ODataDemo.Product",
  "ID": 0,
  "Name": "Widget",
  "Description": "A simple widget",
  "ReleaseDate": "1991-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "DiscontinuedDate": null,
  "Rating": 4,
  "Price": 2.5
}
```

However, when I do that, the service does, in fact use the ID I submitted and return an entity URL using that primary key, *even though an entity with that key already exists.*

When I then try to GET that URL, the response simply says `Syntax Error`. When I query the entire collection, I can see that there are now TWO entities with `ID=0`, the one that previously existed and the one I created.

Is this simply a bug in the reference service implementation? Or does OData really not have a provision to deal with the (presumably very common) scenario of letting the service assign primary keys when creating entities?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have the same question

Comment: @Justin I did not solve this conclusively, but for the particular service I am integrating with I was told that the primary key WOULD be autogenerated and would NOT trigger a validation error if it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

This **IS a BUG** in the service implementation.
Most likely the `ODataDemo.Product` has not been declared with an identity seed in the ORM or the underlying database.

The *red flag* is that if the result of posting with an ID of zero (or any ID), allowed you to create multiple rows with the same ID and no errors were raised then that data type is not correctly defined.

In a service the operates as you expected (seeding the identity column on your behalf), the result would be that the Id in the response would be the next incremental Id for the underlying database table, and not the ID you passed in.

> An implementation that allows multiple rows to have the same ID is not OData v4 compliant, unless of course the ID column *IS NOT* the primary key column. The syntax for selection or operating on a single record depends on the existence and declaration of the column that can be used to uniquely reference each row.
>
> > This is the column that is referenced by the value `11` in the brackets in the url: `.../Products(11)`